# template django-simple-captcha? line break between image and input field

Tags: python, django, web

I have the django-simple-captcha working but I am curious how I can specify in my template where the image appears. right now I have.

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_captcha">Captcha:</label><br>
    {{ form.captcha }}{{ form.captcha.errors }}
</div>
```

This causes the captcha image and form to be right next to each other but what I want is to have them be separated by a `<br>` tag. I know I can do this by modifying the django-simple-captcha source in my python path, but I want an easier way to do this just in case I use it in any of my other projects. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: have you tried to override the css ?

Comment: I ended up just changing the css with 

.captchaWrapper img {
    display: block;
    }

and assigning my div with the .captchaWrapper class. Seems to work pretty well

Comment: yeah.. i think that is the way to go. It is not worth overriding the templates, etc

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it is to modify your settings and write:

```
CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT = u'%(hidden_field)s%(text_field)s<br>%(image)s'
```

Also you can change the sequence of fields output.